# Not Able to Toggle Class Using React Componnent

Tags: reactjs

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to toggle `.green` class for `#root` using `onClick` in react js?

```js
function toggler(e){
    var x = document.getElementById("root");
    x.classList.toggle('green');
  }



const Button = ({ styleClass, onClick, text }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={e => onClick(e)}
      className={`btn ${styleClass}`}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button styleClass="btn-primary" text='Primary Button' onClick={toggler} />
  </div>
, window.root);
```

```css
#root{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:khaki;
}
.green{
  background:green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried binding the click handler like `this.toggler.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not touch the DOM directly when you're writing React components. React can help you manage your class name with state.

Do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonStyleClass: 'bar'
    }
  }

  toggler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      buttonStyleClass: 'foo'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.state.buttonStyleClass}
        onClick={this.toggler}
      >
        Click me
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mxdi9i7 but is there any online environment that I can test this?

Comment: Chris also pointed out that your CSS `#root` selector is preventing your `.green` selector to take effect because id has a priority of 100 points while the class only has 10 points.

Comment: My code example should give you a good understanding of the best practices in writing a React component.

Comment: Thanks again Thanks mxdi9i7 but my question was changing the background of another element not the button element like `#root` for example or `body` but not the button iteself

Comment: Where is this #root element located in your component tree? is it it's parent component? or in the same component

Answer (score 0):

The *problem* here is that id-selectors have higher priority over class-selectors in css. Since you have defined the base color with `#root`, you can't toggle it with just `.green`.

Many solutions here, but one of them could be `#root.green`, adding `!important` or selecting your root otherwise.

That being said, you should not mutate the DOM directly when using React. It voids one of its biggest advantages. See mxdi9i7's answer for more info.